# Rally richtext scripts

Tags: rally

I'm creating a custom kanban board, which in it I want to allow the user to edit the description of a story or defect in a richtext editor. I couldn't find any documentation for a richtext editor I could use, but looking at the source of the /slm/ar/edit pages I found the following snippet of code.

```
Rally.alm.LegacyBootstrapper.onReady(function(){
            var editor = new RALLY.ui.richtext.EditorBuilder().
                withValue('This is a description of a story').
                build('description',
                      'userStory',
                      '#########');

            editor.render('descriptionEditorContainer');
        });
```

I'd like to make use of the editor builder but I can't figure out how to reference it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at [Rally.ui.dialog.RichTextDialog](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.dialog.RichTextDialog) for an AppSDK2-compliant hook to the Rally rich text editing tool.